# Mostrar datos de opción múltiple con JSON usando una función multiselect

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

Obtengo los datos almacenados en BD mediante una consulta `ajax`, pero al intentar mostrar el dato de *tecnologia* en un `<select multiple>` no los muestra como seleccionados.

Este es el HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones.js"></script>
  <link href="multiselect/fSelect.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="multiselect/fSelect.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function($) {
          $(function() {
              $('.test').fSelect();
          });
      })(jQuery);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <br/>
  <div id="contenedor">
    <br/><br/>
    <label>DNI</label>
    <input type="text" id="dni"> 

    <br/><br/>
    <label>NOMBRE</label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre"> 

    <br/><br/>
    <label>APELLIDO</label>
    <input type="text" id="apellido"> 

    <br/><br/>
    <label>CELULAR</label>
    <input type="text" id="numero"><br/>
    <br/><br/>
    <select class="test" id="tecnologia" name="tecnologia[]" multiple="multiple">
     <option value="2g">2G</option> 
      <option value="3g">3G</option> 
     <option value="4g">4G</option> 
     <option value="tdd">TDD</option>
      </select>
      </br></br>
    <button onclick="anadir();">Añadir</button>
    <button onclick="actualizar();">Modificar</button>
    <button onclick="eliminar();">Eliminar</button>
    <input type="submit" onclick="buscar()" value="buscar">
  </div>

  <div id="ventana"> 
  </div>
  </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Y esta es la solicitud ajax:

```
function buscar(){

    var parametros={"dni": $("#dni").val(),}
    $.ajax({

            type: 'post',
            url: '../lunes-2/buscardatos.php',
            data: parametros,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(d){
                $("#nombre").val(d[0]);
                $("#apellido").val(d[1]);
                $("#numero").val(d[2]);
                $.each(d[3].split(","), function(i,e){
                 $("#tecnologia option[value='"+e+"']").prop("selected",true);
                });

            }
        });
}
```

Esto es lo que obtengo al ejecutarla:

[image: entonces recoge los datos de el mysql, pero no muestra las opciones selecionadas]

Pero en la base de datos sí está registrado:

[image: pero en la base de datos si esta registrado]

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu pregunta? ¿Qué problema encuentras usando ese código que muestras? ¿Qué mensajes de error encuentras al usarlo?

Comment: mi pregunta lo acabo de publicar como foto, ya que no llama a los valores selecionados

Comment: No tiene sentido que repitas las mismas imágenes, mejor reestructura tu pregunta para abreviarla sin sacrificar detalles relevantes.

Comment: que biblioteca estas usando? que es `multiselect/fSelect.js`?

Comment: el multiselect es una carpeta donde estoy añadiendo el fSelect.js, que es el javascript de mi elemento multiselect... o en todo caso tendras alguna js que reemplaze a mi fSelect.js?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que deberias hacer es usar en tu input una funcion que consulte los datos de tu db algo asi:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="dni" onkeyup="miFuncion($(this).val());">
<script>
function miFuncion(dni){
  if(dni.length=="8"){
    alert("Consultar el DNI: "+dni);
  }//end if
}//end function 
</script>
```

usando jquery, contamos cuantos digitos tiene tu dni y si esta completo lo traes del db y muestras en tu html
[Revisa el resultado aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/8rgwoLkL/)